# Create parallax clouds with random Y coordinate using SKSpriteNode and SKAction in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a parallax cloud effect with different speeds and sizes but i'm having a hard time when trying to add a different Y coordinate, not always in the same Y for all the clouds.

So I have 5 clouds, with its respective X and Y coordinate, and I use the SKAction.moveByX() function.

All the clouds starts from for example FRAME_WIDTH + 200 (out of bounds) and they end at -100. After that I reset the X to FRAME_WIDTH + 200 and do a "forever" sequence.
That was working perfectly, but I would like to add a random Y coordinate every time the animation finishes.
I was able to do it, but that would only change the Y coordinate once.

How can I achieve this?

Here's my current code:

```
func addClouds() {

        let cloud1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud1")
        let cloud2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud2")
        let cloud3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud3")
        let cloud4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud4")
        let cloud5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cloud5")

        cloud1.zPosition = ZIndexPosition.CLOUD
        cloud1.position = CGPoint(x: self.FRAME_WIDTH - 100, y: self.FRAME_HEIGHT / 2 - 150)
        cloud1.size = CGSize(width: 44, height: 14)

        cloud2.zPosition = ZIndexPosition.CLOUD
        cloud2.position = CGPoint(x: self.FRAME_WIDTH + 150, y: self.FRAME_HEIGHT - 100)
        cloud2.size = CGSize(width: 104, height: 16)

        cloud3.zPosition = ZIndexPosition.CLOUD
        cloud3.position = CGPoint(x: self.FRAME_WIDTH - 50, y: self.FRAME_HEIGHT - 200)
        cloud3.size = CGSize(width: 8, height: 6)

        cloud4.zPosition = ZIndexPosition.CLOUD
        cloud4.position = CGPoint(x: self.FRAME_WIDTH + 200, y: self.FRAME_HEIGHT / 2 - 50)
        cloud4.size = CGSize(width: 116, height: 32)

        cloud5.zPosition = ZIndexPosition.CLOUD
        cloud5.position = CGPoint(x: self.FRAME_WIDTH, y: self.FRAME_HEIGHT - 250)
        cloud5.size = CGSize(width: 24, height: 6)


        let resetCloud1YPos = SKAction.moveToY(self.randomCloud1, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud2YPos = SKAction.moveToY(self.randomCloud2, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud3YPos = SKAction.moveToY(self.randomCloud3, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud4YPos = SKAction.moveToY(self.randomCloud4, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud5YPos = SKAction.moveToY(self.randomCloud5, duration: 0)

        let resetCloud1Pos = SKAction.moveToX((self.FRAME_WIDTH * 2) - 100, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud2Pos = SKAction.moveToX((self.FRAME_WIDTH * 2) - 150, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud3Pos = SKAction.moveToX((self.FRAME_WIDTH * 2) - 50, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud4Pos = SKAction.moveToX((self.FRAME_WIDTH * 2) - 200, duration: 0)
        let resetCloud5Pos = SKAction.moveToX((self.FRAME_WIDTH * 2) - 20, duration: 0)

        let moveCloud1 = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 28)
        let cloud1Sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCloud1, resetCloud1Pos, resetCloud1YPos])
        let cloud1Forever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(cloud1Sequence)

        let moveCloud2 = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 24)
        let cloud2Sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCloud2, resetCloud2Pos, resetCloud2YPos])
        let cloud2Forever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(cloud2Sequence)

        let moveCloud3 = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 35)
        let cloud3Sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCloud3, resetCloud3Pos, resetCloud3YPos])
        let cloud3Forever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(cloud3Sequence)

        let moveCloud4 = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 13)
        let cloud4Sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCloud4, resetCloud4Pos, resetCloud4YPos])
        let cloud4Forever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(cloud4Sequence)

        let moveCloud5 = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 18)
        let cloud5Sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveCloud5, resetCloud5Pos, resetCloud5YPos])
        let cloud5Forever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(cloud5Sequence)

        cloud1.runAction(cloud1Forever)
        cloud2.runAction(cloud2Forever)
        cloud3.runAction(cloud3Forever)
        cloud4.runAction(cloud4Forever)
        cloud5.runAction(cloud5Forever)

        self.addChild(cloud1)
        self.addChild(cloud2)
        self.addChild(cloud3)
        self.addChild(cloud4)
        self.addChild(cloud5)

    }
```

randomCloud1,2,3,4 and 5 is just a random generation within the screen height bounds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, the following code should help you:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import SpriteKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        //create and position a test SKSpriteNode
        let cloud = SKSpriteNode()
        cloud.color = SKColor.blueColor()
        cloud.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width - 100, y: 400)
        cloud.size = CGSize(width: 44, height: 14)
        self.addChild(cloud)

        //pass the SKSpriteNode into the moveNode function
        self.moveNode(cloud)
    }

    //reposition the node
    func repositionNode(node: SKSpriteNode) {
        print("repositioning node")
        node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - 100, self.randomCloudPosition())
        print(node.position.y)
        self.moveNode(node)
    }

    //move the node again
    func moveNode(node: SKSpriteNode) {
        node.runAction(SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 28), completion: {
            self.repositionNode(node)
        })
    }

    //return a random number between 300 and 799 (change this for your specific case)
    func randomCloudPosition() -> CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(500) + 300) //should be between 300 and 799
    }
}
```

You should be able to create your five clouds (or however many) and then just pass each one into `moveNode` and the animation will continue indefinitely

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Great to hear- Enjoy

Comment: @msqar please note that I edited the code to be more concise. You can simply pass the cloud node into the moveNode function the first time.